# number of distinct field values in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, unique, distinct-values

My model has two fields called "userName" and "comments" and I want to get the numbers of all of unique user name that have wrote a comment (A user may have written multiple comments).

When I use the code below I will get the correct answer:

```
const uniqueUsers = (await MyModel.distinct("userName")).length;
```

But when I use countDocuments method, the result is the count of all userNames in my model (including the duplicated ones.)

```
const uniqueUsers = await MyModel.distinct("userName").countDocuments();
```

Here is some sample data:

```
{
   id: ObjecId('6283809b114d345809794af9')
   "userName": "john",
   "comment": "I like it",
   "__v": 0
},
{
  _id: ObjecId('6283809b114d345809794afb')
  "userName": "peter",
  "comment": "I will try it",
  "__v": 0
},
{
   _id: ObjecId('628380a5114d345809794aff')
   "userName": "john",
   "comment": "As i said i like it",
   "__v": 0
},
{
  _id: ObjecId('628380ad114d345809794b03')
  "userName": "jack",
  "comment": "No, I don't think so",
  "__v": 0
}
```

How do I fix this? What's the best practice to solve this type of problem?
Also regarding performance, is there a better way to get distinct values in large collection?
Best Regards.

Comment: Please provide sample data: 3 example documents

Comment: @nimrodserok Hey, I just edited the post and added sample data.

Comment: No problem with your first line of code. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @nimrodserok True but i just want to know what is best practice to do it? Also I'm curious why countDocuments() doesn't working with distinct query?

Comment: @Druid , you may also use aggregation group/addToSet but it may perform worst: https://mongoplayground.net/p/FleTKOYJ83R

Comment: @R2D2 Thank you for your suggestion, your code actually performs 1 sec faster with actual database and my current hardware setup.

Comment: Btw, it is important to do multiple executions when you compare , since if data is already in memory after distinct() execution can show  faster times ...